# Ошибка при запуске потока

Tags: java, многопоточность, исключения

Есть следующий код:

```
@Override
public void doSomething(Action action) {
    if(action == Action.GO){
        try{
            if(!t.isAlive()) t.start();
        }catch(IllegalThreadStateException e){System.out.println(x + " " + y);}
    }
}
```

Этот метод вызываеться другим потоком каждые 0.2 секунды. При завершении работы потока t, начинают выводиться x и y (это значит что выпадает IllegalThreadStateException). Вот код который вызывает этот метод:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Graphics g = Controller.getPanel().getGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    man.getHealth().paint(g, (man.getX()) * 10 - 8, (man.getY()) * 10 - 15);
    g.drawImage(man.getSprite(), man.getX() * 10, man.getY() * 10, Controller.getPanel());
    ((Teamate)man).setRouter(router);
    man.doSomething(Action.GO);
    ((Teamate)man).setRouter(new Router(30, 30));
    man.doSomething(Action.GO);
}
```

А вот метод setRouter():

```
public void setRouter(Router router){
    if(!t.isAlive()){
        this.router = router;
        this.direction = router.getDirection(this);
    }
}
```

Boт Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.LTP.AC.Objects.Teamate.doSomething(Teamate.java:94)
    at com.LTP.AC.main.Game.actionPerformed(Game.java:24)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Почему вылетает Exception, и как все таки запустить поток сново по завершению?

Comment: а что за объект хранится в `t`? дайте полный stack trace исключения.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman t = new Thread(new Runnable(){code});

Comment: Выглядит как попытка запустить уже запущенный поток. Кроме того, многопоточную работу с компонентами графического интерфейса лучше выполнять специально предназначенными для этого методами, типа [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)'а..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `IllegalThreadStateException` возникает на строке `if(!t.isAlive()) t.start();`. Так как экземпляр(объект) потока может быть запущен только один раз. В методе `start` эта проверка выглядит так:

```
/**
*……
* Ноль означает состояние потока новый(не запускался).
*/

if (threadStatus != 0)
    throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

Если ваш поток должен запускается каждые `n` секунд/минут/дней/и т.д. то для этого можно использовать `ScheduledExecutorService`, например, как вот так:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println(LocalTime.now()),
  0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```